# Adding focus to a UISearchBar in custom UIView programmatically not working

Tags: uiview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

What I am trying to achieve is to have a button click action trigger a uiview popup with a search bar at the top of the view, which then displays a UISearchBar and a UITableView below. I have been successful at implementing these events, but when clicking inside the search bar nothing happens. The search bar just has the word search and a search bar button. I have subclassed the UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, and UISearchControllerDelegate for the ViewController. As mentioned, I am doing this programmatically in Swift without a storyboard. There are no outlets or actions. I am calling methods to perform the necessary actions.

```
private var resultSearchController: UISearchController!
    private var  locationSearchTable = LocationSearchTable()

func didClickSearchButton() {

        locationSearchTable = LocationSearchTable()
        locationSearchTable.tableView.delegate = self
        resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: locationSearchTable)
        mapSearchTable.tableHeaderView = resultSearchController?.searchBar
        resultSearchController.delegate = self
        resultSearchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
}
```

I am adding the searchBar to the tableView header and it does show up.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    layout()
}
```

Calling the 'layout' in the SuperView works.

```
private func layout() {

        popupView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        popupView.addGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer)
        didClickSearchButton()

        popupView.addSubview(resultSearchController.searchBar) //Tried adding this to the view, but all it did was put it in a different location.
        popupView.addSubview(openTitleLabel)
        popupView.addSubview(searchButton)
        popupView.addSubview(mapSearchTable)
        view.addSubview(popupView)

        popupView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        popupView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomConstraint = popupView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: popupOffset)
        bottomConstraint.isActive = true
        popupView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 467).isActive = true 

        searchButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        searchButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popupView.leadingAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
        searchButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popupView.trailingAnchor, constant: -50).isActive = true
        searchButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popupView.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true

        openTitleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        openTitleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popupView.leadingAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
        openTitleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popupView.trailingAnchor, constant: -50).isActive = true
        openTitleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popupView.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        openTitleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popupView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)

        mapSearchTable.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        mapSearchTable.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popupView.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
        mapSearchTable.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popupView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        mapSearchTable.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popupView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        mapSearchTable.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popupView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        mapSearchTable.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popupView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

I can see all of the elements, but there is no focus inside the text field when clicking on the input box.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the issue was with the alpha value that was a stored property in the UISearchBar class I created to handle the rendering of the searchBar. I had the value for the alpha set to '0' and after removing that value I was able to render the UISearchBar normally.